# Spring's Observability API alternative for @Timed annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, metrics, micrometer, observability

We're upgrading our app to Spring boot 3 and the new Observability API. In the old way we would just create a timedAspect bean and that would allow us to use @Timed annotations to automatically create metrics for those methods/classes.

The new spring ObservabilityAPI does not seem to provide an aspect oriented way of adding metrics to ObservationRegistry. Does spring boot or micrometer provide any alternative to the @Timed annotation for collecting metrics in this new observability system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The new spring ObservabilityAPI does not seem to provide an aspect oriented way of adding metrics to ObservationRegistry

This is because the `ObservationRegistry` is for `Observation`s, the `MeterRegistry` is for `Meter`s.

If you want to create a `Timer` (which is a `Meter`) just use `@Timed` and `TimedAspect` as you did before, there is nothing wrong with it. If you want more advanced features with the Observation API, you can use `@Observed` and `ObservedAspect`.